# My javascript code doesnt print what i expected it to print

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript objects.
I am trying to output my object's role but it outputs the prototype instead..

```js
function familyMember(role, name, age) {
  this.role = role;
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
var father = new familyMember("Dad", "Alex", 50);
var mother = new familyMember("Mom", "Nilly", 51);
father.role = function() {
  return this.role;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = father.role();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

This is what it prints for me..

"function (){ return this.role; }"

Comment: And what is you expected?

Answer (score 2):

Why well you override

```
role = "Father"
```

with

```
role = function()
```

It does not magically keep the string and the function when you use the same variable name.

Answer (score 2):

```
father.role = function() {
   return this.role;
}
```

In this function, this is father so this.role is father.role: the function. You have overriden the value. You should name it something like `father.getRole` ( or even better `familyMember.prototype.getRole` )

Comment: thanks, I didn't even realize it, I followed w3schools and didnt even see they used another prototype... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Or define a function which actually returns the Role instead of overwriting it with a function?

```js
function familyMember(role, name, age) {
  this.role = role;
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.getRole = function() {
    return this.role;
  }
}
var father = new familyMember("Dad", "Alex", 50);
var mother = new familyMember("Mom", "Nilly", 51);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = father.getRole();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to return "Dad"?  If so, you need to remove the second part and just keep it like this:

```
function familyMember(role, name, age) {
  this.role = role;
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
var father = new familyMember("Dad", "Alex", 50);
var mother = new familyMember("Mom", "Nilly", 51);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = father.role;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above you were overwriting some things. I adjusted what you had to remove some code that wasn't needed and update some of your variable names to stop the overlap.

```js
function familyMember(role, name, age) {
      this.memberRole = role;
      this.memberName = name;
      this.memberAge = age;
    }
    var father = new familyMember("Dad", "Alex", 50);
    var mother = new familyMember("Mom", "Nilly", 51);
    
    
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = father.memberRole
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is, because you overwrite this.role with your function.

1. you create father with this.role as "Dad"
2. You overwrite this.role with your function
3. You insert this.father (and thereby your function) into the HTML

Simply use a different name for your function like getRole().

```js
function familyMember(role, name, age) {
  this.role = role;
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
var father = new familyMember("Dad", "Alex", 50);
var mother = new familyMember("Mom", "Nilly", 51);

father.getRole = function() {
  return this.role;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = father.getRole();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```